# Java can't verify that an array list of another type has an element of string type

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to access to an array list and add a new instance of another class only if there are no elements with that name in the array list itself..
Implementation:

```
private final ArrayList<MyExternalClass> count = new ArrayList<MyExternalClass>();

public boolean operate(String test) {      
    if (!count.contains(test)) {      
        count.add(new MyExternalClass(test));      
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This doesn't work and return me true also with the same string sent to the method. How can I solve?

Comment: Why do you expect a `String` to be found in an `ArrayList<MyExternalClass>`?

Comment: What does `MyExternalClass` contain? And why `!count.contains(test)` when the `count` ArrayList contains a `MyExternalClass` object and not a `String` object?

Comment: `List.contains(test)` will iterate over the elements until it finds an element which returns `element.equals(test) == true`. As you can see, `MyExternalClass.equals(String)` won't work and even though you could implement that method so that it accepts strings too, this would break the contract because you'd need `String.equals(MyExternalClass)` as well (theres no guarantee either `a.equals(b)` or `b.equals(a)` will be called. - However, you can just iterate over the elements yourself and stop once you've found an element that matches. With Java 8+'s streams that becomes a one-liner.

Comment: Adding to my comment above: try `if( !count.stream().filter( e -> e.getWhateverIsTest().equals(test) ).findFirst().isPresent() ) { ... }` (or as of Java 9 you could use `if( ...isAbsent() )`).

Comment: @Thomas: anyMatch() is the appropriate method here, not filter().

Comment: @JBNizet you're right, I had the feeling I missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `List` contains `MyExternalClass` objects, `contains(String)` will always return false. You need to iterate over the objects in the `List` and see if the `String` property of the class matches the given `String`. Java 8+ you can do:

```
public boolean operate(String test) {          
   if (!count.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.strVar.equals(test))) {      
      count.add(new MyExternalClass(test));      
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Just a curious question, what is strVar referring to over here? (:

Comment: @cokeby190 That is referring to the `String` variable of `MyExternalClass` that the original poster wanted to test against

Answer (score 0):

Use [SET](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of list. Set works same as list but same element can not be added to the list more than once.